# Raw HTML in chatroom descriptions

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, mobile-web

Chatroom descriptions display raw markup instead of links:
[image]

The bug is specific to mobile sites. Example of how Python room description is supposed to look:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arguably it's better to have too much encoding than too little :)

Fixed now, thank you.